# Swift - Creating and reading a 2D HashMap

Tags: swift

I can't find any proper tutorial of how to do this.

I tried:

```
var hashMap = [Int:[String:String]]()

hashMap[7]["height"] = "bla"
hashMap[7]["align"] = "blatoo"

print(hashMap[7]["height"])
```

It prints nil

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your type `[Int:[String:String]]` there is first is the `key` is type `Int` and the value is dict `[String:String]` and the dict `[String:String]` has key is type `String` and value is `String`

So `[String:String]` here is value of key `7` in your `hashMap`

The right way to do that is creating a dict which will be the value of key `7`

Code will be like this

```swift
var hashMap = [Int:[String:String]]()

var dict = [String:String]()

dict["height"] = "bla"
dict["align"] = "blatoo"

hashMap[7] = dict

print("hashmap: ", hashMap[7]?["height"]) // Optional("bla")
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't even compile, because the getter of the first level (`[7]`) may return `nil`. To make it work like you intend to, you need to tell the getter to return a default value in case the entry doesn't exist. You want it to return a new, empty dictionary in this case:

```
var hashMap = [Int:[String:String]]()

hashMap[7, default: [:]]["height"] = "bla"
hashMap[7, default: [:]]["align"] = "blatoo"

print(hashMap[7]?["height"])
```

To make it little nicer to use, you can provide a setter function:

```
func set(int: Int, key: String, value: String) {
    hashMap[int, default: [:]][key] = value
}

set(int: 7, key: "height", value: "bla")
set(int: 7, key: "align", value: "blatoo")
```

Comment: Nice way too, thanks, I upvoted

Comment: @user19559647: This comes in handy for things like: `var counter: [String: Int] = [:] ; counter["foo", default: 0] += 1`